# Android Studio project level build.gradle error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently can`t sync my project because of project-level build.gradle.I thought it was corrupted and tried 
1)Deleted caches(.AndroidStudio3.2/system/caches)
2)Invalidate Caches/Restart
3)Deleted the following files: .idea, .gradle, gradle, appname.iml, app.iml, 
4)Deleted .gradle/wrapper/dists
P.S All other projects syncs.
build.gradle code:

```
  <component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-1.1.3">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/constraint-layout-1.1.3.aar/6e5d62e725623f0f1060b115dcb600fe/res" />
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/constraint-layout-1.1.3.aar/6e5d62e725623f0f1060b115dcb600fe/jars/classes.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

Error:startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Yol\build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
   
   ^

1 error
[build.gradle screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oto97.png)

Thanks for response)

Comment: What did you try to achieve?

Comment: Solving this error. Because I cant sync my file while there is error

Comment: I'll ask you in anotter form, when this occurred? What did you do when it stopped working? What was your last modification?

Comment: This problem occurred when I started android studio. It wasn't there I just closed android studio and next time when I started it occurred. I hadnt changed anything in my code

Comment: Something like this happened to me once but I solved it by just deleting Android studio's caches. But now this solution not working  (It was about a month ago and after that, I worked on this project and there wasn't any problem)

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle files are written in Groovy, not XML, like you have there. I don't know how you ended up having that file as build.gradle, but the syntax is invalid, and that is what is causing the problem. Check https://developer.android.com/studio/build

Comment: I think it is a bug in Android Studio. Because there is a lot of question  about this problem in StackOverflow

Comment: It may be. But you just have to replace your build.gradle file with a valid one. Check the link I provided for a template.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Sync Project with Gradle File" from top menu - it might be helpful for you

Comment: tell me your gradle version

Comment: it is gradle-4.6

Comment: take project backup first and then go to "AndroidStudiox.x\system\caches" and delete all the caches and sync project again

Comment: Tried it about 10 times till yesterday